# How to extract the arguments or labels

Tags: list-manipulation

This will be probably labeled as duplicate but I couldn't find the answer.

I want to know how to extract the name or the argument of functions or strings in general. For example when applied to `function[x]` gives `x` or `namex` gives `x`. Here `x` will be a number.

Comment: `First @ function[x]`?

Comment: Yes, it is working, thx. I wouldn't expect that at all.

Comment: "Everything is an expression". `{1, 2}[[0]]` -> `List`, `{1, 2}[[1]]` -> `1`, `function[x][[0]]` -> `function`.